# Load iframe sources into Foundation Modal after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, zurb-foundation

I'm creating a one page portfolio site using Foundation that is simple at first, but then if you click on links modals pop up feeding in the html src from other pages.  However, I want the sources of these modals to load after the page loads (around 10mb of images trying to load). What is the best way to do this in jQuery/js?

I have around six of these modals:

```
<a data-reveal-id="more-info-modal" class="small round button">View Project Details</a>

<div id="more-info-modal" class="reveal-modal large" data-reveal>
  <div class="modal-frame">
    <iframe width="100%" height="600px" src="more-info.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best practices is to use AJAX to load content into the modal.

and Reveal modal lets you do it

```
<button data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="http://some-url">
Click Me For A Modal
</button>

<a href="http://some-url" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">
Click Me For A Modal
</a>
```

or you can use JS to configure it

```
    // just an url
$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open', 'http://some-url');

// url with extra parameters
$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open', {
    url: 'http://some-url',
    data: {param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'}
});

// url with custom callbacks
$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open', {
    url: 'http://some-url',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('modal data loaded');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('failed loading modal');
    }
});
```

for more configuration options refer this link[link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)